# Can any noun be duplicated like 人人 and 天天?

Tags: grammar

I'm familiar with duplication of nouns to mean "all" or "every", such as

> 打扫卫生人人有责。
>   Everyone is responsible for cleaning up.
>
> 好好学习天天向上。
>   If you study well you will improve every day.

Can the same structure be used for any noun?

> 狗狗有尾。
>   All dogs have tails (?)
>
> 腿腿疼手手冷。
>   Both of my legs hurt and both of my hands are cold (?)
>
> 熊猫熊猫很可爱。
>   All pandas are cute (?)

Are these acceptable sentences?

Comment: 手手 腿腿 or something like this seems too cute to be widely used in daily life. If you talk like this on a daily basis, people would think you too pretentious. Although these might be frequently used to talk with toddlers. Anyway, these are not regularly used in communications, let alone in formal texts.

Comment: 手手 or 腿腿 or 狗狗 do not mean "all" or "every", it is just a "cute" way of saying things.

Comment: And note that, the whole sentence is supposed to be cute to match 手手 etc. Say, 来~把手手拿出来啦给爸比帮你洗洗白白噢☆（Never talk this way in daily life!）

Comment: Another side note, the use of dual character word may have different frequency in different Chinese accents. For exmaple, for people speaking Southwest Mandarin (西南官话) and Jin Chinese (晋语), they may say much more 叠词 in their daily communication.

Answer (score 3):

You can do 狗狗, 腿腿 or 手手. But this usage doesn't show plural. Usually girls use these kinds of words to act cute.

熊猫 already contains two characters so we don't say 熊猫熊猫.

Answer (score 2):

You may found that duplicating an **object** to means *every **object***, the rule only apply to some date & time words or measure words. There are no general rules, just idiomatic expression.

年年 = 每年 every year
岁岁 = 每年 every year
月月 = 每月 every month
日日 = 每日 every day
天天 = 每天 every day
人人 = 每人 every body
个个 = 每个 every **something**
次次 = 每次 every time

分分秒秒 = every moment
时时刻刻 = every time
点点滴滴 = bits and pieces of life
年年岁岁 = every year

Answer (score 1):

很遗憾，并不是所有名词都可以重复，这类重复的词称为叠词。
人人 AA type
金灿灿 ABB type
急急忙忙 AABB type
以上只是很少的几个例子，还有很多种结构